# SQL is breaking on a character I didn't put in my code

Tags: php, sql, syntax

I'm getting a syntax error on this PHP code:

```
<snip>
$last = (isset($_GET['last']) && $_GET['last'] != '') ? $_GET['last'] : 0;

$query = "SELECT message_id, user_name, message, date_format(post_time, '%h:%i') AS post_time" . 
    " FROM message WHERE chat_id = " . db_input($_GET['chat']) . " AND message_id > " . $last . ";";

$message_query = db_query($query);
</snip>
```

And `db_query`:

```
function db_query($query, $link = 'db_link') {
    global $$link;

    $result = mysql_query(mysql_real_escape_string($query), $$link) or db_error($query, mysql_errno(), mysql_error());

    return result;
}
```

The exact error is this:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds 
to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\' %h:%i\') 
AS post_time FROM message WHERE chat_id = 1 AND message_id > 0' at line 1<br><br>
SELECT message_id, user_name, message, date_format(post_time, '%h:%i') AS 
post_time FROM message WHERE chat_id = 1 AND message_id > 0;
```

As you can see, it's throwing an error on a character that I don't have/see in my code.  What is going on here?

Comment: Are you sure you're not escaping the whole query string? Could you include your query calls as well?

Comment: Well, post the exact code you're using, but it seems some portion is adding slashes where it shouldn't.

Comment: @John:why don't you echo $query before using?

Comment: @Hoàng: Echoing $query outputs the correct (without the '\') query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `mysql_real_escape_string` only on your variables, not on the whole sql query.

Now it is translating:

```
date_format(post_time, '%h:%i')
```

to:

```
date_format(post_time, \'%h:%i\')
```

By the way, I´m assuming that your `db_input` function prepares your variables for use with a database, so you definitely need to use that for your `$last` variable as well.

Comment: Sure enought, that was it.  Thanks.  BTW, I can't accept for 4 more mins.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$query = "SELECT message_id, user_name, message, " . 
date_format(post_time, '%h:%i') . "AS post_time" . " FROM message 
WHERE chat_id = " . db_input($_GET['chat']) . "AND message_id > " . $last . ";";
```

Try to call date_format outside the string  `" . date_format(post_time, '%h:%i') . "`